# unable to run IOS app in Compose multiplatform

Tags: build

I am working on a Compose Multiplatform project for Android, ios, and Web that runs on Android and Web, but not on ios.

```
The following build commands failed:
```

Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.
PhaseScriptExecution Compile\ Kotlin\ Framework /Users/vikassharma/Developer/shubham/compose-kmp/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-F36B1CEB2AD83DDC00CB74D5.sh (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
(1 failure)

```
Task :composeApp:kspKotlinIosSimulatorArm64 FAILED
```

error: KLIB resolver: Could not find "co.touchlab:stately-concurrent-collections" in [/Users/vikassharma/Developer/shubham/compose-kmp, /Users/vikassharma/.konan/klib, /Users/vikassharma/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-2.0.0-Beta3/klib/common, /Users/vikassharma/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-2.0.0-Beta3/klib/platform/ios_simulator_arm64]
error: Compilation finished with errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':composeApp:kspKotlinIosSimulatorArm64'.

> Compilation finished with errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
My problem was in coin-core version
I rolled-back it from 3.6.0-wasm-alpha2 to 3.6.0-alpha3, and it helped.
In toml file:

```
[versions]
koin = "3.6.0-alpha3"
[libraries]
koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
```